# UITableViewCell labels and multiple lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is it possible to get an out of the box UITableViewCell's labels to do multiple lines without subclassing?  I tried the following settings but it's not working.  The labels get positioned like you would expect with the expected spacing between labels but I only ever get a single line of text.

```
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sizeToFit` after `text` is set

```
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"this string is too long to fit on one line";
[cell.detailTextLabel sizeToFit];
```

Comment: It doesn't work in the delegate call but it does work in `-layoutSubviews` in a `UITableViewCell` subclass so at least I don't have to do any measuring.

Comment: Do you mean in the datasource call?  I just added it to a cellForRowAtIndexPath for one of my non-subclassed, UITableViewCells and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work for me there.  `-sizeToFit` only works in `-layoutSubviews` for me.

Comment: layoutSubviews of what class?

Comment: In a UITableViewCell subclass.

Comment: This solution is fine.  I just didn't want to have to do any text measuring.  UITableViewCell lays out all the frames correctly but just doesn't set the size of the frame for whatever reason.

Comment: Glad it works, but I thought you didn't want to subclass the uitableviewcell.  Anyway, I can tell you that a generic table with a generic cell and this code applied in the datasource has the desired behavior.  You might consider proving that to yourself in a fresh little test project.

Comment: I did.  I don't know what to tell you but it doesn't work or me that way.  It only works in a subclass.  I am creating everything programmatically so there might be a difference there versus using storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

i can't add a comment to your post so i need to post a response:

try to change the cell.detailTextLabel frame too

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I don't want a solution where I would have to subclass or measure text.  UITableViewCell is adjusting the frames correctly  depending on the number of lines for text but it's only showing a single line of text in the expanded frame.